# NodeJs Samples with LCD screen

Tags: pi-3, node.js

I am having a hard time trying to find nodejs samples with the groovepi and pi 3. I want to do a simple hello world. I found a groovepi sample with intel edison, but obviously that didn't work.

Doing a little research, I found the johny five library but that it's only for Arduino, but they are supposed to have plugins for other boards, like Raspberry, so I installed rasp-io and johnny five and tried to run this sample.

```
var raspi = require('raspi-io');
var five = require('johnny-five');
var board = new five.Board({
io: new raspi()
});

board.on('ready', function() {

var lcd = new five.LCD({
controller: "JHD1313M1"
});

lcd.bgColor(r, g, b).cursor(0, 0).print(f);
});
```

I get this error:

> pi@raspberrypi:~/share/Sample2 $ node index.js modprobe: ERROR:
> ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep
> file '/lib/modules/4.4.26-v7+/modules.dep.bin' child_process.js:531
> throw err; ^
>
> Error: Command failed: modprobe i2c-dev modprobe: ERROR:
> ../libkmod/libkmod.c:557 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep
> file '/lib/modules/4.4.26-v7+/modules.dep.bin'
>
> at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:488:13) at execSync
> (child_process.js:528:13) at new I2C
> (/home/pi/share/Sample2/node_modules/raspi-i2c/lib/index.js:120:33) at
> new Raspi
> (/home/pi/share/Sample2/node_modules/raspi-io/lib/index.js:161:14) at
> Object. (/home/pi/share/Sample2/index.js:5:7) at
> Module._compile (module.js:571:32) at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (module.js:580:10) at Module.load (module.js:488:32) at tryModuleLoad
> (module.js:447:12) at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)

I want to do a simple hello world on the LCD display I got in they key

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error comes from trying to run a new program without rebooting your rpi. I got the same error after installing OpenVPN and trying to run it asap.

I did the following to "solve" this problem:

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```